# Take the mean of the top 10% values according to the date

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consist of the day column and a score column. So per day, there are many values. So I need to get the mean of the top 10% values per day. Simply means I need the output as a day column and mean of the top 10% values of that day.

[this is a example dataset screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mImxx.png)

```
`{'Date': 
 [
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1),
  datetime.date(2021, 4, 1)],
 'value': [     
  3.35,
  1.85,
  1.3,
  1.85,
  1.85,
  1.17,
  1.17,
  2.8,
  1.43,
  2.54,
  1.22,
  2.54,
  1.17,
  1.17,
  2.71,
  5.98,
  1.39,
  1.48,
  16.46,
  1.43,
  8.39,
  33.99,
  2.54,
  11.8,
  2.13,
  2.24,
  2.92,
  1.35,
  1.54,
  2.52]}`
```

Comment: can you please paste the outcome of `print(df.head(30).to_dict('list'))` in your question? Because if you share your data in text form, we can use it with much less effort.

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty simple -

*Assuming you're using Pandas, and this is a pandas dataframe called `df` with columns `date` and `value`

*Creating a demo dataframe and importing required packages, you would probably import your table as a dataframe!*

```python
import pandas as pd
import math
import statistics

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-04-01','2021-04-01','2021-04-01','2021-04-01','2021-04-01','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02'],
                   'value': [12,32,12,23,12,14,15,54,43,64,21,15]})

#If you need to save results as a DataFrame later on
res = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date','top_10p_mean'])
```

1. Filter based on dates

*Basically getting a list of different dates and iterating through them to get values in a list*

```python
for date in df['date'].unique():
   temp = list(df['value'][df['date'] == date])
```

2. Sort filtered set by values

*Sorting the list in reverse order to have highest values at the top or you can just omit the `reverse=True` part to keep values as is*

```python
   temp.sort(reverse=True)
```

3. Take mean of top 10% values

*This will calculate the number of items in top 10% of the list (the index is rounded up to the next integer), take those values and calculate the mean.*

*Further explanation of the functions for beginners -*

*First "round_up_to_next_integer(total_number_of_items(in_list) * 10%)"*

*Then "give_me_mean_of(list_items[from_index_0 : the_number_I_got_from_the_percentage_calculation])"*

```python
   avg = statistics.mean(temp[0:math.ceil(len(temp)*0.1)])
```

4. Print it or save in a new DataFrame

*Printing the results and appending it to the previously created empty DataFrame*

```python
   print('Mean value on ' + str(date) + ' = ' + str(avg))
   res = res.append({'date': date, 'top_10p_mean': avg}, ignore_index=True)
```

So in total it should work something like this -

```python
import pandas as pd
import math
import statistics

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-04-01','2021-04-01','2021-04-01','2021-04-01','2021-04-01','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02','2021-04-02'],
                   'value': [12,32,12,23,12,14,15,54,43,64,21,15]})

df
Out[]:
          date  value
0   2021-04-01     12
1   2021-04-01     32
2   2021-04-01     12
3   2021-04-01     23
4   2021-04-01     12
5   2021-04-02     14
6   2021-04-02     15
7   2021-04-02     54
8   2021-04-02     43
9   2021-04-02     64
10  2021-04-02     21
11  2021-04-02     15

res = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date','top_10p_mean'])

for date in df['date'].unique():
   temp = list(df['value'][df['date'] == date])
   temp.sort(reverse=True)
   print(temp)                                            #Just to show what it looks like
   avg = statistics.mean(temp[0:math.ceil(len(temp)*0.1)])
   print('\nMean value on ' + str(date) + ' = ' + str(avg) + '\n')
   res = res.append({'date': date, 'top_10p_mean': avg}, ignore_index=True)

Out[]:
[32, 23, 12, 12, 12]

Mean value on 2021-04-01 = 32

[64, 54, 43, 21, 15, 15, 14]

Mean value on 2021-04-02 = 64

res
Out[]: 
         date top_10p_mean
0  2021-04-01           32
1  2021-04-02           64
```

Comment: @PasinduUkwatta Don't forget to select is as accepted answer if it does what you want

Comment: @Delta._.43 Isn't there a solution that doesn't require transforming all the values to a list? Since OP mentioned that he has many values, it could become a performance issue

Comment: I'm not sure if you can dynamically sort it to get the largest values, which is the main reason I thought of converting it to a list. If you don't need to sort the data, one can simply slice the required number of observations directly from the table.

But if you have to sort, I think you'll have to iterate through the whole thing anyway. Maybe someone else can provide a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

[df.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) is what you want.
First determine how many values correspond with 10% by running (`df` being your dataframe):

```py
highest10p = 0.1*len(df)
```

then you can select the 10 largest values in the `value` column by using

```py
df.nlargest(highest10p, 'value')
```

So if you want the mean, you use `.mean()` function:

```py
df.nlargest(highest10p, 'value').mean()
```

Comment: I got your idea, so in that case, first of all, I need to get them sorted with dates, then I can follow your approach, which means the first sort the values with dates, then calculate the 0.1 of the length and then get the mean of  data in the 0.1 according to the date

Comment: Exactly! The code that I put here should work on the data that you provided i.e. once you estracted all the values for a single date.